# Knockout js multiple data-bind updat only 1 input calendar

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to have multiple DatePicker (from jquery ui) and set the values with knockout.js

The problem is that always, any input date text update only the first input date, and the correct function should be that each calendar update their own control

```
$(function () {
    $(".ExpiredDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true
    });
});
```

And the html is this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Sectors">
   <input id="date" style="width: 120px!important;" maxlength="10" style="width: 80px;" data-bind="value: ExpiredDate, datepicker: ExpiredDate" />
</div>
```

Some idea?

Comment: How is your `datepicker` custom binding look like? How is your viewmodel look like? Why do you need to call  `$(".ExpiredDate").datepicker()`? In your sample your input does not have the class `ExpiredDate`...

Comment: That was a little error, but, not is necessary have this line, but the problem alway ocurred, as if all the calendars were linked to the first

Comment: It would help to see the view model...

Comment: @Skyp
`var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Sectors = ko.observableArray();

self.viewSectors = function (e) {
            $.ajax({type: "POST",url: url, dataType: "json",contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',success: function (data) {self.Sectors(data.Result);}
            });
        };
}`

In the result, the dates are "" (empty string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you have an 'id' tag in your input. Remove it and it will work.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Sectors">
   <input style="width: 120px!important;" maxlength="10" style="width: 80px;"     data-bind="value: ExpiredDate, datepicker: ExpiredDate" />
 </div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ktpGr/#update
(note that in the date format is not respected in this fiddle)